# if an ajax request brings in a chunk of javascript code, should I expect it to be executable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

if an ajax request brings in a chunk of javascrpt code, should I expect it to execute?

for example, if an ajax request brings in a another ajax request and deposits it in the page, how can i make it functional?

```
$("select#select_host").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo $sn; ?>/admini/list/is_active/'+$(this).val(),
              type: 'get',
              asynch: 'false', 
              dataType: 'text' ,
              success: function(response) {           
              $("#list_hosts").html(response);
              }   


        });  

    });
```

Comment: You should probably rethink your design.   I am sure there are many examples of security risks, especially running a GET request for this.  Think of what you really need this to do and then make a function that can handle a variety of data to do what it needs OR  simply have a file of the possible JS functions that you would need to run and call the correct one (with or without extra data) from your response.

Comment: Title and body do not really match. The answer to the title question is "No".

Answer (score 1):

The technic you're talking about is called **[JSONP](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/jsonp-sop/)** and is used all the time to bypass the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

What you'll be doing, basically would be to insert `<script>` tags with actual `Javascript` per AJAX call.

Hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase Ian Malcolm, it's not so much whether you *can*, it's whether you *should*.

There are two ways you can execute code that has come from a server and it generally depends on where that code came from.

Javascript has a function called `eval()`, which takes a string and executes it as Javascript. The main concern with this is when you can't be sure what that string contains. In the world of Internet security, most people would argue that you can *never* be sure of incoming data and so you should **never** use `eval` on incoming data.

The other method is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). This method allows you to pull data from remote sources. It does this by generating a `<SCRIPT>` tag which pulls in remote Javascript. Your call to the JSONP source will usually include a callback function that is called upon receipt of the JSONP data, giving your local code access to it.

Without knowing precisely what you wish to achieve, I don't want to make any assumptions, but let me make some suggestions.

Calling code on demand from the server can by a little heavyweight. I can't think of many (read - *any*) scenario whereby calling bespoke functions from a server would be the best approach. However, I *can* imagine a scenario whereby you have a large set of potential functions that you might want to execute and you don't want to load them all into the browser at one time. I'd suggest two approaches:

1. Perform the functions on the server. Just send you data to the server in some format and have it return a result set. Leave the processing to the server
2. If you need a function that you don't currently have available on the browser, load in the script file containing that function, then call the function in your Javascript. Think of those files as Dynamically Loadable Libraries that you call in as and when you need them. You're limited to your own server using this method which improves security (if you trust that your own server isn't going to send malicious code.

In short, I'd argue that a design that requires you to immediately take text from a server and execute it as code may indicate a problem in that design. But you didn't come here for a design review, so hopefully those suggestions will help you find a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be able to call "eval()" with the resultant data as the parameter, and it will run the code. HOWEVER, using eval is *strongly* discouraged for security reasons. For example, remember to **NEVER** ***EVER*** evaluate code that you get from the user.

You should look into other ways to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to get to the goal. I´d advise you to take a closer look at
[jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). With the .live handler you needn´t to evaluate the returning code again. It is done by jQuery.
My second advise is: Use JSON.
From PHP you can return an array with [json_encode()](http://de.php.net/json_encode) and use the array by jQuery.each. By this, you can write the list, without eval() ;-)

```
("select#select_host").change(function(){

    var data = {'is_active':$(this).val()};
    // Use jquery.post, it´s simple and plain
    jQuery.post('/admini/list', data, function (JSON) {

        jQuery.each(JSON.data, function(key, list)
        {
          $("#list_hosts").append('<li>'+list+'</li>');
        });
      }, "json");
```